# October CMS partial field in backend dont render twig

Tags: octobercms

I have component default.htm in which I have some logic

```
{% set vilas = vilas.vilas %}
<ul>
    {% for vila in vilas %}
    <li>{{vila.name}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and when I display it on frontend like homepage it's working fine.

But when I use partial field in backend and use partial path :

```
$/plugin_author/plugin_name/components/component_name/default.htm
```

...this partial field not render twig.

When I edit record in backend this field showing twig syntax like text.

I want to display same logic in backend how it is on frontend, in this case lists of Vilas.

Comment: the backend will not support twig syntax. it is for front end only but you can use php tag in backend (for ex. <?php ...YOUR_CODE  ?>)

Answer (score 1):

Backend partials do not support TWIG, but they do support PHP (as Zakir has pointed out).

Unfortunately, the support for PHP is pretty rudimentary. You can't actually perform conditional logic in the partial; you can only echo a string / number.

If you want to perform conditional formatting in the backend partial you should create a function in the related controller, then use `<?= $this->myCustomFunction(); ?>` in the partial.